# How to zoom without following the cursor in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion, accessibility, system-preferences

In OS X Lion, I want to zoom in to an area of the screen, and then lock the zoom there regardless of where I move my cursor (by default the zoomed-in area will follow my cursor position).

I read about a hack where you press CmdShift4 and then Esc while zoomed, but that didn't work for me.

The zoom options are under *System Preferences > Universal Access > Seeing > Zoom*.

Comment: *Only when the pointer reaches an edge* is the best you can do. What you want is the opposite of accessibility. Please explain what you actually want to achieve, maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: I'm a web developer. So I want to zoom in on an area of the screen while I adjust pixel alignment, colors, etc.. So I would have an area of the screen zoomed in while i'm editing code or using Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right tool for the job. In this case, [xScope](http://iconfactory.com/software/xscope), which gives you a zoom loupe that can be locked.

[image: Screenshot]